# Sitecore Media Framework custom fields indexing

Tags: solr, frameworks, sitecore, media, brightcove

I'm using Media Framework 2.1, the Brightcove version. I have been able to get it working with videos imported without any problems. I'm creating some pages based on the videos using Solr for search and videos bucket. There are some custom fields in Brightcove, that are getting imported. But I don't think the custom fields are getting indexed into sitecore_web_index or sitecore_master_index.

Am I wrong to think that these fields are not getting indexed? I checked these fields using Luke and they are not there in the index files.

If these fields are not getting indexed, how can I get them indexed so I can run queries against them? I'm not sure if there are any code samples to read custom fields values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The custom field is stored as a string on the video item so it would be something like - field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3.

I have to then read these values and created computed fields based on the values.

The field values can be accessed like item.Fields[custom field id/name].Value.